# Improve performance on List<byte[]>.Count by criteria

Tags: c#, performance, collections, count

I have a `List<byte[]>` where I load information into that represents a matrix. Each `byte` in the array represents the segment it belongs in per criteria. So there can be multiple criteria's like Age, Income etc, and each criteria will be segmented.

An example of how this byte array might look in HEX is `0x0D1A0006`

I represent the matrix on a form with Controls that is created depending on how many Criteria items there are, and how many Segments there are per Criteria, and each control knows in which criteria it belongs, and which segment of the criteria.

I loop through the controls then and use a lambda expression `FilteredData.Count(x => x[curCriteria] == curSegment)` to determine the count all the items in the list that correspond to the `curCriteria` and `curSegment`.

Is there a way to get the counts by not looping through the controls, but rather returns for me the count per segment in a specific criteria? Something like:

```
int[] = FilteredData.Count(x => x[curSegment]).ToArray<int>()
```

Here is some test data.

```
0x0E0C060E0003070C0203000A0B090B00
0x010C060E0004020C020309090B010B00
0x050C060E0001070C020500080B080B00
0x000C060E0004060C020D090C01040B00
0x070C080E0003040C0005010D0B0D0B00
0x050C060E0001050C020C090B0B030B00
0x0D0C060E0003080C0203030A0D080B00
0x030C060E0004040C02010008070A0B00
0x0A0C060E0004050C020C020B0B0C0B00
0x050C020E0001020C01050A060B020B00
0x050C060E0003080C020D000C08030B00
0x040C060E0000050C020D030C0B060000
0x000C030E0007040C070709050C090B00
```

My Matrix is basically 15 Criteria's and there layout is as follows:

```
Criteria 1, 15 Segments
Criteria 2, 13 Segments
Criteria 3, 10 Segments
Criteria 4, 15 Segments
Criteria 5, 9 Segments
Criteria 6, 8 Segments
Criteria 7, 10 Segments
Criteria 8, 14 Segments
Criteria 9, 15 Segments
Criteria 10, 15 Segments
Criteria 11, 11 Segments
Criteria 12, 15 Segments
Criteria 13, 14 Segments
Criteria 14, 15 Segments
Criteria 15, 13 Segments
```

There can be 30-40 Criteria's and maximum 64 Segments per criteria

Comment: `List` has property [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) to return number of all items. If you apply a filter there is no way to avoid iteration. You can try to cache result and invalidate it when collection is changed.

Comment: I don't want the Count in the list, I want to see how many in the list have Segment 1 Criteria 1 selected etc. from the sample data, Segment 1 will have the following values `2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1`

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of your data its difficult to say, but some abstraction of the underlying data may be in order, anyone coming to this kind of code would really struggle and bugs would be very tricky to find. As part of that abstraction you could then provide optimizations (caching as Sinatr says) to improve performance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you have a performance issue? Unless there's a performance issue, just keep to the simplest code possible - there's ways to optimize this (of course, with its own trade-offs), but they're going to hurt readability and memory usage. Given the numbers you give for the criteria and segments, I find it highly unlikely you're having performance issues - unless you're doing this in a loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a very simple solution, but you can store your items in separate lists along with the "all kind of item list", and then access `Count` property on separate lists to get the count of specific kind of item.

In other words: instead of querying the count by criteria, store your data by criteria.